# IDE contoller not found in viirtual box

Tags: controller, ide, virtual-machine, virtualbox, sta

Iam following the tutorial [here](https://www.techspot.com/guides/503-windows-8-virtual-machine/).

[Tutorial Image(IDE controller is shown)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsNIm.png)

In my virtual box I cannot find the IDE controller mentioned here.

Answer (score 0):

if you can't see that you have to press the "plus" green icon in the right corner of storage tree window and select controller ide to add the option